# get names of online users

Tags: php, ajax, refresh

as i have mentioned at my earlier post, we are creating a chat for a specific website. Now this chat would have to retrieve the names of the users online and would automatically update once one user would log out of the chat. we were able to create this with the use of PHP alone and right now we are trying to use jquery to avoid often refreshing.so far, this is what we have:

```
     <?php
     session_start();       //Configuation
     ?>

     <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://www.pinoyarea.com/videochat/css/winterblues.css">

    <?php

       $name = $_SESSION['username'];
       $room = $_SESSION['room'];
       $user = $_SESSION['user'];
       if($name == NULL || $room == NULL || $user = NULL)
       {
          echo "<script>window.location = 'http://www.pinoyarea.com/index.php?p=member/signup';</script>";
       }
     include "connect.php";

     $timeoutseconds = 60; // length of session, 20 minutes is the standard
     $timeoutseconds_idle = 30;
     $timestamp=time();
     $timeout=$timestamp-$timeoutseconds;
     $timeout_idle=$timestamp-$timeoutseconds_idle;
     $PHP_SELF = $_SERVER['PHP_SELF'];
     if (!empty($_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"]))
     {
       //check for ip from share internet
       $ip = $_SERVER["HTTP_CLIENT_IP"];
     }
     elseif (!empty($_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"]))
     {
        // Check for the Proxy User
        $ip = $_SERVER["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
     }
     else
     {
       $ip = $_SERVER["REMOTE_ADDR"];
     }
     $temp = @mysql_query("SELECT * FROM useronline WHERE online_name='$name' AND online_user='$user' AND online_room='$room'");
      $rowie = @mysql_num_rows($temp);
     // Add this user to database
      $loopcap = 0;
      while ($loopcap<3){
      if($rowie == 0 AND $name != NULL)
      {
      @mysql_query("insert into useronline values('$timestamp','$ip','$PHP_SELF','$name','$room','$user')");
      }
      else
         {
         } // in case of collision
      $timestamp = $timestamp+$ip{0}; $loopcap++;
      }

       // Delete users that have been online for more then "$timeoutseconds" seconds
          mysql_query("delete from useronline where timestamp<$timeout");

       //Modified

       // Select users online
       $result = @mysql_query("select distinct online_name from useronline"); 
       $result2 = @mysql_query("SELECT distinct online_name FROM useronline WHERE online_room='$room'");
       $user_count = @mysql_num_rows($result2);
        mysql_free_result($result);
       @mysql_close();


     // Show all users online
     echo '<table name="tableonline" width="180px">';
     if ($user_count==1) 
      {
   echo '<tr><th>';
   echo '<font size="1px" style="font-family:arial;"><strong>'.$user_count.' Toozer Online</th></tr>';
      } 
      else 
      {
     echo '<tr><th>'.$user_count.' Toozers Online</strong></font></th></tr></table>';
      }

     echo "</table><br /><table width='180px'>";
     while($cell = mysql_fetch_array($result2))
    {
   $timestamping = $cell["timestamp"];
   if($timestamping >= $timeout_idle && $timestamping < $timeout)
  {
      $src = "http://www.pinoyarea.com/images/videochat/user-offline.png";
  }
   else
  {
    $src = "http://www.pinoyarea.com/images/videochat/user-online.png";
  }
      echo '<tr><td><img src="'.$src.'"/><font size="1px" style="text-decoration:none;font-family:tahoma;"></td><td>'.$cell["online_name"].'</font>';
      echo '<br /></td></tr>';
     }
    echo '<table>';

   ?>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.4.2.min.js">  </script>
  <script>
  $(document).ready(function() {
  $("#tableonline").load("online_users.php");
   var refreshId = setInterval(function() {
   $("#tableonline").load('online_users.php?randval='+ Math.random());}, 3000);
   });
   </script>

    //<META HTTP-EQUIV="Refresh" CONTENT="10">
```

Comment: So.... what's the problem?

Comment: Are you trying to comment out that meta refresh tag? If so, `//` won't work in html, you need `<!-- ... -->`

Comment: The problem is, once a user goes offline the list does not update. Meaning the name of the offline user still appears on the list of online users.We trying to automatically update the list of online users when a user turns offline.

Answer (score 0):

You have to put a boolean value for the user in the DB (in the user table). when he get's login ie when he enter's to his profile page the BOOL value should be changed to 1 and when he get logout change the vlaue to 0.